# Outlook 2007 - Bulk Renaming of Personal Folders?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have seen this question in regards to bulk renaming of file folders, but not bulk renaming of personal folders in outlook - so the question is - is there anyway to bulk rename personal folders in Outlook 2007?  What I would like to do is select several folders at once and make the same change to each of them - for example if I have several folders named123.01, 123.02, 123.03, etc. I would like to be able to change the 123 to 132 without having to rename each folder on an individual basis

Answer (score 0):

I'd say VBA. You can open your personal folders (PST) file and loop through the folder objects, renaming those that match your desired string. I don't think there's a OTS tool for this.

Comment: OTS - Off The Shelf